# call list type method in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
public static List<contact__c> conNews(Integer num , String channel){ 
//some stuff;    

}
```

Test class:

```
 List<contact__c> li = conConsole.List<contact__c>(1,'rr');
```

How to call this line given Error:

> Unexpected token: '('

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling wrong method. Replace your code with following code:

Test Class:
`List<contact__c> li = conConsole.conNews(1,'rr');`